# Need help with new ceiling fan wiring

Tags: ceiling-fan

So I bought a new remote ceiling fan. I can't get the fan to turn on while connected to the receiver. I have a black, green, red and white wire coming out of my ceiling. I have all 3 greens connected together, the ground. I have the black from ceiling connected to the black from receiver labeled "AC in L". White from ceiling connected to white on received labeled "AC in N". I have my red capped. Then on the other side of the receiver I have black,blue and white connected the same colors on the fan. Doing this I can't figure out why my fan won't turn on.

But when I take off the receiver I connect black from ceiling to black on fan, white on ceiling to white on fan and the red to blue on fan. The fan will work and my room switch turns the light on and off. I'm assuming the red from ceiling controls the switch on my wall.

Comment: Are you sure the receiver is any good?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes?

Comment: Does the receiver require pairing to remote? You had the correct wiring going for you, red woud be capped, however, red could have also been your hot in, and capping that caused the other hot to not function. You need to find your hot at the switch. See how the switche(s) are wired also.

Comment: check the battery in the remote control